# How to darken postscript text produced by emacs

Tags: emacs, postscript

I'm using emacs command ps-spool-buffer-with-faces command to make some postscript files of code I'm working on. The problem is that the font color seems to be light gray instead of black. I've poked around the postscript file & googled a bit, but have not found any solution. Does anyone know how to turn my gray font black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to print in black and white, try:

```el
(setq ps-print-color-p nil)
```

Otherwise, you might take a look at other values for ps-print-color-p:

> ```
> ps-print-color-p is a variable defined in `ps-print.el'.
> Its value is t
>
> Documentation:
> Specify how buffer's text color is printed.
>
> Valid values are:
>
>    nil        Do not print colors.
>
>    t      Print colors.
>
>    black-white    Print colors on black/white printer.
>       See also `ps-black-white-faces'.
>
> Any other value is treated as t.
>
> You can customize this variable.
> ```

You can customize using <kbd>M-x</kbd>**customize-variable**<kbd>RET</kbd>**ps-print-color-p**<kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thanks.... I eventually found a webpage suggesting (setq ps-print-color-p nil), which I put in my .emacs file, but this is *far* more informative/useful than what I found.